# How to increase VoIP call security?

Tags: encryption, voip

I am using VoIP for my office because I can use the same number whether I am in USA or anywhere else.

I am using it on my laptop and I have to visit India in the next few days. My friends say rules are regulations in India are not that organized and that my calls can be hacked in that country.

I have asked my VoIP provider ([Axvoice](http://www.axvoice.com)) and they say their service will remain secure where ever I go (including India).

Regardless, I want to take some extra steps on my own to make data as well as my VoIP calls 100% safe. I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw back your VoIP "data path" (to use a simple name for the way the data packets may go through the internet), you'll see something like this in terms of steps:

- You -> your ISP
- Your ISP -> axvoice
- axvoice -> wherever

You're guaranteed that axvoice->wherever is secure, through what they have said. You, however, are not guaranteed of steps 1 or 2, or at least not explicitely. You'll need to dig up the SIP defs given by Axvoice as to whether there is any form of end-to-end encryption (i.e. if the traffic all the way to you requires decryption). If there is, halleluiah. If there isn't, all is not lost: get on a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sebastien that a VPN is the easiest route. I'll add that there are VOIP clients with strong encryption like Jitsi that you and the other party can use if you want end to end security w/out trusting axvoice. End-to-end encrypted VOIP is a better way of talking to people in a corruption-rich country as you only have to trust that person and they'll know what you say anyway.